# GridLayout is not displaying in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout(2,1) made up of two more GridLayouts(8,4). I added the (2,1) layout to my main JFrame but when I run it only one of the 8,4 Layouts shows up. What I want to happen is both of them appear stacked on top of each other.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Pos extends JFrame {

JTextField oneTicks;
JTextField twoTicks;
JTextField threeTicks;
JTextField fiveTicks;
JTextField tenTicks;
JTextField twentyTicks;
JTextField twentyFiveTicks;
JTextField thirtyTicks;

JTextField[] ticks = { oneTicks, twoTicks, threeTicks, fiveTicks, tenTicks,
        twentyTicks, twentyFiveTicks, thirtyTicks };

JTextField oneAmount;
JTextField twoAmount;
JTextField threeAmount;
JTextField fiveAmount;
JTextField tenAmount;
JTextField twentyAmount;
JTextField twentyFiveAmount;
JTextField thirtyAmount;

JTextField[] amounts = { oneAmount, twoAmount, threeAmount, fiveAmount,
        tenAmount, twentyAmount, twentyFiveAmount, thirtyAmount };

JLabel oneLabel = new JLabel("$ 1 Games");
JLabel twoLabel = new JLabel("$ 2 Games");
JLabel threeLabel = new JLabel("$ 3 Games");
JLabel fiveLabel = new JLabel("$ 5 Games");
JLabel tenLabel = new JLabel("$ 10 Games");
JLabel twentyLabel = new JLabel("$ 20 Games");
JLabel twentyFiveLabel = new JLabel("$ 25 Games");
JLabel thirtyLabel = new JLabel("$ 30 Games");

JLabel[] gameLabel = { oneLabel, twoLabel, threeLabel, fiveLabel, tenLabel,
        twentyLabel, twentyFiveLabel, thirtyLabel };

JLabel oneXLabel = new JLabel("X $ 1");
JLabel twoXLabel = new JLabel("X $ 2");
JLabel threeXLabel = new JLabel("X $ 3");
JLabel fiveXLabel = new JLabel("X $ 5");
JLabel tenXLabel = new JLabel("X $ 10");
JLabel twentyXLabel = new JLabel("X $ 20");
JLabel twentyFiveXLabel = new JLabel("X $ 25");
JLabel thirtyXLabel = new JLabel("X $ 30");

JLabel[] multiLabel = { oneXLabel, twoXLabel, threeXLabel, fiveXLabel,
        tenXLabel, twentyXLabel, twentyFiveXLabel, thirtyXLabel };

Pos() {
    initJTextField(ticks);
    initJTextField(amounts);

    JPanel lottoPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    JPanel startGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 4));
    JPanel endGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 4));

    initLottoPanel(startGrid);
    initLottoPanel(endGrid);

    lottoPanel.add(startGrid);
    lottoPanel.add(endGrid);

    this.add(lottoPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

}

// init all JTextfields
void initJTextField(JTextField[] jArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++) {
        jArray[i] = new JTextField();
    }
}

void initLottoPanel(JPanel panel) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gameLabel.length; i++) {
        panel.add(gameLabel[i]);
        panel.add(ticks[i]);
        panel.add(multiLabel[i]);
        panel.add(amounts[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pos pos = new Pos();
    pos.setSize(600, 600);
    pos.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pos.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pos.pack();
    pos.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both panels are being added to the JFrame, however one of them is completely empty. When you call your initLottoPanel method, you are actually reassigning all of your sub-components (JLabels, JTextFeild, etc) to the new panel being pass.

To fix this, you need to have have two set of sub-components, with each set corresponding to only one panel.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that I can't share sub-components among panels. So I would have to make another set of all these components right? Although that seems very redundant. If that's what I got to do then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same instances of of the objects in `gameLabel`, `ticks`, `multiLabel`, and `amounts` into both startGrid and endGrid.  That is like adding 1 object into 2 different locations into the JFrame

If you change this portion of your constructor

```
initLottoPanel(startGrid);
//initLottoPanel(endGrid);

lottoPanel.add(startGrid);
//lottoPanel.add(endGrid);
```

and you will see the startGrid(because now the objects are only loaded into the JFrame once)